# Please explain the line of code I Mentioned

Tags: python, django, mixins, django-class-based-views

This is a mixin which I had seen in a book.

```
from django.core.cache import caches
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_cookie

class CachePageVaryOnCookieMixin:
    cache_name = 'default'

    @classmethod
    def get_timeout(cls):
        if hasattr(cls, 'timeout'):
            return cls.timeout
        cache = caches[cls.cache_name]
        return cache.default_timeout

    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        view = super().as_view(*args, **kwargs)
        view = vary_on_cookie(view)
        view = cache_page(timeout = cls.get_timeout(), cache = cls.cache_name)(view)
        return view
```

In as_view() `view = cache_page(timeout = cls.get_timeout(), cache = cls.cache_name)(view)`
what is the use of (view) at last. Is it a type casting?

Comment: Possibly offtopic, maybe check code reviews SO?

Comment: The `(view)` is a call to a `callable` with `view` as the parameter.

Comment: @stephanmg: Code Review is for working code that you wrote yourself (or maintain) and understand. It is not about (1) somebody else's code, or (2) asking how or why it works.

Comment: Graipher: Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache_page` is a function that returns another function that accepts a view as a parameter. This can be also split into two like so:

```py
callable_func = cache_page(timeout = cls.get_timeout(), cache = cls.cache_name)
return callable_func(view)
```